# +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction right on app start

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is very odd...
The message appears right in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Even with a totally empty method.

Say like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And, yes, I'm aware that this doesn't work since there's no rootController defined for the window.
So the app crashes of course - but I still get this `+[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction`.

The app actually works and doesn't crash - but it's still weird as hell and I'd like to get rid of that...

Any ideas?

[Edit]

Here's the stack trace of the app start...

[image]

Comment: I get this message too in Xcode 9 on IOS 11 iPhone X simulator, no idea why